# how to display items using foreach loop? in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm making a webpage for displaying the my services in 3 columns. I'm using foreach loop to fill the data for that service, as I am using loop therefore the services are visible in a single column and when I add more services the length of columns go longer. I'm getting the data of services form database. I want to display services such that it get display in 3 columns and as I add more services, columns remain same but rows get increased.
Here is my code which I'm using.

```
                           <% 
foreach (var product in product_list)

{%>     
<div class="grid_3 alpha" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 289px;">
                                    <img src="<%=product.img %>" alt="" class="img_inner">
                                    <div class="text1"><a href="OrderBook.aspx"><%=product.name%></a></div>
                                    <div class="center">
                                   <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Price" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label> <%=product.price %>
                                    <br />
                                   <a href="_Services.aspx?pro_id=<%=product.id %>&action=add" class="l1" onclick="book_click"><strong id="booknow">BOOK</strong> </a>

                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />

                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Simply if ur foreach loop have data then You can call each column by foreach( var item in YourDataList){   // Now here u have to call  like 
item.YourColumnName }

Comment: i cant post it as answer because it would be just a foreach loop ! if you post some code of your that where and how you are getting then it would be suitable to post a perfect answer

Comment: if i use for eachloop for every column then there will three column  having the same data . i d'nt want that.i want to ensure that every service should be change.

Comment: then my suggestion is to try to fetch the distict record either trying to filtering them on post Time !

Comment: again em saying that nobody can understand your thinking without seeing a bit of your code mayn

Comment: i have edit my post and include the code of foreach loop. is it clear to understand my question ?

Comment: Why not use a Repeater Control?

Answer (score 0):

first make element in aspx page like this

```
<div runat="server" id="test1"></div>
```

then use this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string temp="";
     int i=0;
     foreach (var product in product_list){
      temp+="<div class=\"grid_3 alpha\" style=\"left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 289px;\"><img src=\""+product.img+"\" alt=\"\" class=\"img_inner\"><div class=\"text"+i+"\"><a href=\"OrderBook.aspx\">"+product.name+"</a></div><div class=\"center\"><label  >Price:"+product.price+"</label><br /><a href=\"_Services.aspx?pro_id="+product.id +"&action=add\" class=\"l1\"><strong id=\"booknow"+i+"\">BOOK</strong></a><br />";
      i++;
     }
      test1.InnerHtml=temp;
    }
```